# Singly linked list in java implementation, Infinite printing output?

Tags: java, data-structures

In the below code, I am trying to implement a singly linked list adding elements at beginning of the list. Why am I infinitely getting "5" as output?
Can any one help to fix the problem? What should be the proper implementation to show the list?

Class1:-

```
package linkedList;

public class SinglyLinkedList {

    private int data;
    private SinglyLinkedList next;
    public int getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public SinglyLinkedList getNext() {
        return next;
    }
    public void setNext(SinglyLinkedList next) {
        this.next = next;
    }


}
```

Class 2:-

```
package linkedList;
public class SingleLinkedListImpl   {

    public SingleLinkedListImpl() {
        length =0;
    }
    SinglyLinkedList head;
    private int length;

    public SinglyLinkedList getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public int getLength() {
        return length;
    }

    public void setLength(int length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    public void insertAtBegin(SinglyLinkedList listNode) {

            listNode.setNext(head);
            head = listNode;
            length ++;
    }


    public void showLinkedList(){
        SinglyLinkedList p,q;
        p=head;

        while(p.getNext()!=null){
            System.out.println(p.getData());
            p=p.getNext();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SingleLinkedListImpl impl= new SingleLinkedListImpl();
        SinglyLinkedList linkedList= new SinglyLinkedList();
        linkedList.setData(3);

        impl.insertAtBegin(linkedList);
        linkedList.setData(5);
        impl.insertAtBegin(linkedList);

        impl.showLinkedList();


    }
}
```

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger and you would see why.

Comment: hint: your list is supposed to have two elements but you allocate only one.

Comment: As you step through your code in a debugger, carefully inspect the objects and the values of their fields.

Comment: PS. Rename your class `SinglyLinkedList` to `Node` since that what it is: a single node in the list, not the list.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of the linked list is inconsistent. You never set `next` for `impl`. If you really want to implement a linked list like that, you would have to create a `new SingleLinkedListImpl` for each item you want to add to your `linkedlist`, and set `next`. But I would suggest having a look at a tutorial for how to create a linked list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the object you're inserting into the list - it's the same object you're inserting twice. This means that:

1. The `data` field will always have the very last value you set with `setData()`.
2. You get a cycle because the `next` field is pointing to the same node.

Solution:

Create a new instance of `SinglyLinkedList` for each node you add to the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot yurib, how i missed this :(